# sales.rule.update.coupon.usage not finishing

Tags: magento2, cron, magento2.4.5, queue

I have a new website, with less than 100 sales. And the cron job bin/magento queue:consumers:start sales.rule.update.coupon.usage --single-thread --max-messages=10000 runs without ending. It's been running for 2425998 seconds. Same thing happens if i run on cli.

The table salesrule_coupon_usage is currently empty.